# develop a regex expression that matchs caracters, numbers or special caracters

Tags: regex, scala

I want to develop a regex expression that matchs caracters, numbers or special caracters(`` !#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|\}~ ``)

For example, valid strings are:

```
aaa456
4567777ertttt
!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|\}~ert788888
```

I have written this pattern :

```
val regex = "?: [a-zA-Z0-9]*[!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|\}~]*"
```

but it does not work in some cases :

```
!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|\}~ert788888
```

Have someone idea about that ?

Comment: Move the `-` to the `]`, to the end of the character class. Or escape it. Please format the question, I tried to do it, but please check.

Comment: cam you share some invalid cases too?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew it does not work

Comment: @imen I do not know what should work and what should. Do not use "work". When speaking of regex, we use "matches" or "does not match". First of all, if you need to validate you either need to use `^` and `$` anchors, or use an anchored regex, please add a full code snippet to the question. Then, are you sure there are `?:` at the start? Remove them.

Comment: I would like to develop a regex that matchs an email adress and i talk about the local part : I have modified the implementation . Know I have the regex as belows: 

val localPart = s"""(?>(\\s)|($labelOfLocalPart)(?:\\.$labelOfLocalPart)*)"""

val labelOfLOcalPart = s"""(?:$simpleCharacter{1,63})"""

val simpleCharacter  = """[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]"""

know some cases matchs and some others does not match 

".email@domain.de" => I want that its is invalid but with this pattern it is valid

also this "anonymos..aa@domain.de"

Comment: @imen, please rewrite your question. It is impossible to know what you need without a clear idea of what the desired regex should **not** match. From your current description is looks like the pattern `".*"` should meet your requirements.

Comment: I want to develop a pattern that matchs caracters, numbers or special caracters but not a(.) at the begininng, consecutive points(..)

Comment: That's very different from the way you framed your question. It's also quite difficult to compose a regex to do that. Why not just validate your address string by making sure it fails these 2 tests: `addr.startsWith(".")` and `addr.contains("..")`

Answer (score 2):

OK, I *might* have come up with a pattern that meets your requirements as stated in the comments (the question itself lacks sufficient information to be useful).

This pattern matches any string that starts with a character that is **not** a dot, and that is followed by one or more characters that are either A) **not** a dot, or B) a dot that is **not** followed by a dot.

```
"[^.]([^.]|.(?!\\.))+"
```

With this you can test/validate strings of interest.

```
testString matches "[^.]([^.]|.(?!\\.))+"  //returns true/false
```

Comment: I want a regex that matchs a quoted string " \"hallo\" aaaa "

have you any idea ?

Comment: Is this in addition to the request above, or would this be a completely new/different regex? Match any string that contains two quote marks, or does there have to be characters between the quote marks? Simply identify match/no-match, or should it isolate and return the quoted word(s)? What should happen if there are three or more quote marks? Is there a reason why you don't provide enough information to get your questions answered?

Comment: I want that the regex Simply identify match/no-match. I need not to extract the string between quotes @ jwvh

Comment: `".*\".*\".*"` should do it. You can drop the outside wildcards if it is compiled unanchored: `"\".*\"".r.unanchored`

Comment: have you please idea how to match chinese caracters, greek caracters, accented characters and caracters with "Umlaut" in regex ?

Comment: @imen; A StackOverflow comment is not the place to ask a new question. Start by doing basic on-line research (read [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) for example), then come back to SO with a clear question, showing what you've learned and what is still unanswered. Include examples and/or code (or pseudo-code) to make it clear what you're trying to achieve.